# Recursively put InOrder Binary Search Tree data into an array in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, void-pointers, inorder, double-pointer

I am trying to recursively insert the data stored in each node of my binary search tree into an array, sorted via the InOrder logic of the code.

This is the snippet of the two functions I am using. The "bst_getordered" one's parameters and type cannot be changed, only its contents. The "node_getordered" can be changed in any way necessary.

```
void bst_getordered(bst* b, void* v)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (b == NULL || v == NULL) {
      return;
    }
    node_getordered(b->top, (char*) v, i);
}

int node_getordered(bstnode* node, char* v, int i)
{
   if (node == NULL) {
       return i;
   }
   node_getordered(node->left, v, i);
   v[i] = (char) node->data;
   i++;
   node_getordered(node->right, v, i);
   return i;
}
```

It should store all data in the tree, sorted, into the array. However it does not do it and I cannot figure out why... I think I am supposed to use a double pointer to increment the address but I can't figure out how to go about it... my syntax knowledge is lacking in that field...

[EDIT 1]
This is a snippet of the test program I use to make sure the code works:

```
void test_getordered(void)
{
       int i, sc;
       char words1[WORDS][STRSIZE] = {"it", "is", "a", "truth", 
       "universally", "acknowledged", "that",  "a", "single", "man", "in", 
       "possession", "of", "a", "good", "fortune", "must", "be", "in", 
       "want", 
       "of", "a", "wife"};
       char words2[WORDS][STRSIZE];
       bst* b = bst_init(STRSIZE, mystrcmp, myprintstr);
       bst_insertarray(b, words1, WORDS);
       assert(bst_size(b)==18);
       bst_getordered(b, words2);
       printf("%lu %s\n", sizeof(words2), words2[0]);
       for(i=0; i<17; i++){
                 sc = strcmp(words2[i], words2[i+1]);
                 assert(sc<0);
       }
       bst_free(&b);
       assert(b==NULL);
}
```

[EDIT 2] These are the structures of my node and tree. I suspect I need to increment the counter by the tree->elsz somehow in order to properly traverse through the array:

```
struct bstnode {
   void* data;
   struct bstnode* left;
   struct bstnode* right;
};
typedef struct bstnode bstnode;

struct bst {
   bstnode* top;
   /* Data element size, in bytes */
   int elsz;
};
typedef struct bst bst;
```

Comment: The "v[i] = (char) node->data;
         i++;" bit should definitely be replaced with the right code, i just cant figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

You can send the address of `i` variable and increment the value of it after populating that index.

```
void bst_getordered(bst* b, void* v)
{
    if (b == NULL || v == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    node_getordered(b->top, (char*) v, &i);
}

void node_getordered(bstnode* node, char* v, int* i)
{
    if (node == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    node_getordered(node->left, v, i);
    v[*i] = (char) node->data;
    (*i)++;
    node_getordered(node->right, v, i);
}
```

Comment: I get this error when compiling now:
bst.c:234:16: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'int *' from a function with
      result type 'int'; dereference with * [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
        return i;
               ^
               *
bst.c:240:12: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'int *' from a function with
      result type 'int'; dereference with * [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
    return i;

And when I fix it with "return *i" it still does not work...

Comment: I have edited my answer a little bit. You should not return anything from this function. Plz check the answer again and let me know.

Comment: It did not work again... I've added the test program snippet I use to test this function... it fails at the sc<0 assert.
testbst: testbst.c:115: void test_getordered(): Assertion `sc<0' failed.
The printf gives 460 and an empty space... I wanted to see how big the array is and what the first space in it stores to see if it's really the problem with the function and it appears so...

Comment: I also added the code for my structures now to be more clearer. I think I need to increment not just by i but also add the tree->elsz somehow...

Comment: Is there any way to test if from my side? Currently this is not a full program.

Comment: Is there a way I can send files over? Or just code snippets? I will try uploading all the code if I cannot send files...

Comment: You can put the whole code in question or somewhere else providing the link here.

Comment: Ok here is a link to all the files for the full program. you compile in a C compiler with the command "make -f BSTMakefile testbst" and run it with "./testbst"

The .h file cannot be changed.

https://files.fm/u/g9s77rrr

Comment: I think you are trying to sort a list of strings. In `void node_getordered(bstnode* node, char* v, int* i)`, `v` should be an `array of char*` not `char*`.

Comment: I do yeah, trying to copy strings into the array. I will see how I can go about doing that thank you.